# Writing a callback like the jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

In jQuery you can use callbacks like this:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
 // code
});
```

How can I write something just like i.e.

```
foo.on('bar', function() {  
    // code 
});

foo.on('buzz', function() {  
    //code 
});
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: and more importantly, what are `bar` and `buzz` :)

Comment: You should look at the [observer pattern](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/08/16/javascript-design-patterns-observer/).

Comment: Sorry, this code is not jQuery but I want something that 'looks' like it.  `foo` in my case is a validation module that I want to write (somehow).  `'bar'` and `'buzz'` are various results from the validation module (so they could be `'success'` or `'failure'`).  Just wanted to keep the question general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
var eventBus = function () {

    var supportedEvents = ['bar', 'buzz'];

    var subscribers = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < supportedEvents.length; i++) {
        subscribers[supportedEvents[i]] = [];
    }

    return {
        on: function (event, action) {
            subscribers[event].push(action);
        },

        trigger: function (event) {
            var funsToCall = subscribers[event] || []; // empty array if unsupported event
            for (var i = 0; i < funsToCall.length; i++) {
                funsToCall[i](); // calling a function
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you call the `eventBus` function to get an object that will be your `foo`:

```
var foo = eventBus();

foo.on('bar', function () {
    console.log('bar');
});

foo.on('buzz', function () {
    console.log('buzz');
});

foo.trigger('bar'); // prints 'bar' to the console
foo.trigger('buzz'); // prints 'buzz' to the console
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a valid statement in jQuery, to invoke the method you need to trigger the event using [.trigger(eventname)](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

like

```
foo.trigger('foo')
```

Comment: ...assuming that `foo` is a jQuery instance

Comment: @David yes.. assuming `foo` is a jQuery wrapper object

Answer (score 3):

The following article will be helpful

> **How to Create Custom Events in jQuery**
>
> http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/

jQuery’s .trigger method is the key. You can trigger an event with a new type name and arbitrary data at any point, e.g.

```
$.event.trigger({
    type: "newMessage",
    message: "Hello World!",
    time: new Date()
});
```

Handlers can now subscribe to “newMessage” events, e.g.

```
$(document).on("newMessage", newMessageHandler);
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question.